# How to start an application in a given directory, using other as its working dir?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, path

For a system we are deploying for our customer we need to run the setup executable from %temp% and have it use for the installation, files in another directory. This cannot be solved at the application level. So, basically what I need it to somehow "cheat" the setup.exe located at %temp% to think it ran under another directory.

Any ideas? I tried doing pushd & popd, that doesn't work because the OS tries to call setup.exe from the data files' directory, not setup.exe. I also tried calling setup.exe by running a bat from the data files directory, that basically calls it by doing:

```
%temp%\setup.exe
```

doing:

```
cd %temp%
setup.exe
```

also failed

Comment: have you tried  `cd %workingdir%   \%temp%\setup.exe` ?

Comment: This seems like a programming question.  This can be solved by using system variables.  What version of Windows?  Solutions will be different across certain versions.